# Trouble creating an EB application via CLI

Tags: python, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Laravel App and I'm trying to create a environment in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but when I try to run `eb create`, I'm getting this error:

```sh
ERROR: TypeError - expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I'm using Python 3.8.5.
I've tried to reinstall Python, the same with pyenv, end nothing.
By the way, I'm using Laravel Valet on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question lacks the details on you setup the AWS EB CLI. But it could be one or of 2 things:

- You are using and [old version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) of an AWS EB CLI
- You are using a non stable release of the [current AWS EB CLI (v3)](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup)

You could try installing a different version of the AWS EB CLI. For example:

```sh
python scripts/ebcli_installer.py --version 3.14.13
```